# Strange sleep mode of MacBook behaviour after water damage

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Months ago I drowned my MacBooks keyboard in water and it died. I'm using an external keyboard now the Mac works as before. However, there is this interesting feature that if I just close the Mac (sleep mode?) then it runs hot and the battery drops to 0% within about 15 Minutes. So now if I don't use the Mac, I just keep it open so the battery doesn't go away. What might be the explaination for this new property?

Comment: On some models, the sleep sensor and the battery control board are the same part. Any combinations of failure that you could dream up could be happening. A low battery in general, increased heat in clamshell mode, failure to sleep and failure to regulate power / charge properly would easily account for your observations. What are you really trying to solve here (i.e. what next?)

Comment: @bmike: I don't think it will have been repaired in the future, I'm just interested how this happens.